# Enabling CustomAction table in msi

Tags: c#, mysql, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to add a new custom action to my CustomActions table.The issue is there is no custom action table present in the msi,if i open it with orca.So before inserting into the table should i create the table and then insert.

How to create the new table CustomAction in msi from c# code

[image]

If the table is already present i am able to add properly.Is there a way to activate the custom actions table with predefined definition in the msi.

The code to check if table exist is like this

```
 if (db3.TablePersistent["CustomAction"].ToString() == "msiEvaluateConditionTrue")
            {

                string query = "INSERT INTO CustomAction (Action,Type,Source,Target) VALUES ('" + name + "'," + type + ",'" + source + "','" + target + "')";
                Console.WriteLine(query);
                vw3 = db3.OpenView(query);
                vw3.Execute(null);
                db3.Commit();
                vw3.Close();
            }
```

My doubt is how to create the table if it is not existing.Or is there some direct way to enable these tables.There is an option in the tool Orca to activate a table if it is not persistant in the db.

[image]

Comment: Did you create this MSI? If so, using which tool?

Comment: If you create the MSI with WiX, use [EnsureTable](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/ensuretable.html)  element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the SQL Create Table command - I believe that's how it works. You'd need the definition of the table structure.

More specifically, I believe that all the tools that create MSI files (perhaps including Orca) use schema.msi from the Windows SDK/Kits as a template for whatever they do. The tools don't implicitly know what MSI files look like - they rely on the template from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Save the empty 'CustomAction' table to a .idt file from Orca from an msi having a CustomAction table which is empty. Then we can use the Msidb.exe avilable with windows toolkit to add the table to an msi.

```
Msidb.exe -d File.msi -i CustomAction.idt -f "C:\ABC"
```

The last argument -f is to give the folder path to which the .idt file belongs.This will add the table to the msi after which we can do our insert statements.